# Update foreach array in js

Tags: javascript, foreach

i wrote this code as my XO game project but the problem is that i can't update the array that foreach function uses , the array changes i checked it with console.log but i can't change it for my foreach function , what should i do ?

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const boxes_list = [...boxes];

boxes_list.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    box.innerHTML = "X";
  });
  box.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    box.innerHTML = "";
  });
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const boxIndex = boxes_list.indexOf(box);
    if (boxIndex > -1) boxes_list.splice(boxIndex, 1);
    console.log(boxes_list);
    box.innerHTML = "X";  
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the click listener supposed to do?

Comment: Removing an element from boxes_list won't delete it from the page, or prevent its event listeners from triggering.  I don't know if that's what your assumption is.

Comment: @james , click listener removes that box index from "boxes_list" array and then puts "X" as the box ( div element ) value if you click on each box .

Comment: the `mouseout` event sets innerHTML to `""`. This results in the element becoming unclickable

Comment: yeh i know this but what should i do ? i need to delete it from the page in order to create this game.

Comment: @AhsanKhan , yes you are right but how can i keep the hover feature ? i want to be able to see X when i hover on each box .

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the box.  But that will make the remaining boxes shift to take up the space.  If that's ok, your click listener can just be:

```
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    box.remove();
  });
```

But if you want to make the remaining boxes stay in place, then I'd suggest not deleting the element but hiding it by setting the visibility css attribute to hidden.  Here I do that by assigning another class "invisible" to the box.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const boxes_list = [...boxes];

boxes_list.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    box.innerHTML = "X";
  });
  box.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    box.innerHTML = "";
  });
  box.addEventListener("click", () => {
    box.classList.add("invisible");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```